# CMD password change

Tags: cmd

On my computer, the command`net user [username] %random%`
I have been confused about this, since I did not use the `/random` command. Does anybody know what the password would have been set to, and if so, what?
(Or at least what the possibilities are or how to fix it **WITHOUT DATA LOSS**)

**This is the administrator account**

Comment: *"Or at least what the possibilities are"* A number between 1 and 32767 (inclusive) http://ss64.com/nt/syntax-random.html

Comment: `for /l %%i in (0,1,32767) do (title %%i & runas /user:Administrator cmd /k "echo %%i")` - will give you 32766 errormessages but eventually a window with the correct number.

Comment: @Stephan how would I run that? I only have the administrator account, and I am running Windows 8.1. Is there a way to run it from an SD card, or would I need to use some sort of password reset disc?

Comment: you would run it from another account on your computer. If you don't have one, that's (sorry to say) bad. If you got a password reset disk: yes, use that. If not - well, it's only 32767 possible passwords... I found several possible solutions with google "windows password lost" - if you trust such solutions. If not, get a WinPE to boot from and backup your data, then reinstall your OS.

Answer (score 0):

you can`t do any thing !
you should reset your OS.